# How do I share my badges after completing the exercises in Codecademy?

Tags: sharing

I have finished the exercises in [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) and I would now like to share all the badges the site notified me about during the course, via social channels (such as Facebook and Twitter). How can I share my progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this. The only way to share your progress via social networks is when you actually receive the badge. (Via the banner that appears at the top of the page)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible right now via Codecademy to share the entire portfolio of your badges. [Source](http://help.codecademy.com/customer/portal/questions/281268-sharing-badges). However, it is a feature that they are looking into.

After each successful completion, after the last step when you click on "Next Section", on the top of the page there will be temporary bar where you can click and share your badge (that particular one you just completed) on Facebook / Twitter and beyond. But it is a transient option.

Answer (score 0):

There may not be a handy share button, but there is a way to do this.

The easiest way is to go back to your account, i.e. http://www.codecademy.com/user_name. In the right hand column you'll find your badges.

Clicking on one of the badges there will take you to your Achievements page (/users/user_name/achievements), but note that the end of the URL reflects what badge you've just clicked, i.e. http://www.codecademy.com/users/user_name/achievements/course-ruby-beginner-en-X5wcR

Take that URL and paste it on Facebook, and have a look at the preview of the link. Facebook will automatically suck in the Facebook meta data of the page, which just happen to come from the badge you want, even though the link takes the visitor to your general Achievements page.